# Deploying api documentation from .chm files

Tags: c#, html, web, documentation, sandcastle

I am currently working on documenting our now massive code base. I can use sandcastle to generate .chm files that contain the xml comments I have inserted into the code. My question now I guess is: What next? I would like to be able to host them on our server as a website instead of me having to pass out the documentation to the people that may need it now or in the future. I know the question is vague (I'm not 100% sure what I'm even looking for) but any tips or help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) allows for output to Website via the HelpFileFormat setting. In this mode, a complete ASP.NET website is generated from the documentation. The look and feel is extremely similar to the .chm.

[image: Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI]

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't realize it was that simple. How do I compile the generated output and test it in a browser? I can't load it into vs and I want to try to format it a bit to look good.